# Get response in JSON format in Yii2

Tags: php, json, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to convert and array of response into JSON format. I have tried all the answers that were posted on SO and other websites like [web1](http://www.thecave.info/output-json-header-in-php/),[web2](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php) adding `header('Content-Type: application/json')` and then `echo json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`
But I'm always getting the output in text format.
Can some one help me in solving this.

Helpers Class:

```
public static function renderJSON($data) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

My Controller:

```
if ($model->login()) {
    $user =  User::findByUsernameOrEmail($request->post('username'));
    $userArray = ArrayHelper::toArray($user);
    Helpers::renderJSON($userArray);
```

I tried to printing the `userArray` and it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => abc
    [lastname] => xyz
    [username] => test_test
)
```

Json output: (html/text)

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "lastname": "xyz",
    "username": "test_test"
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Set

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
```

in the controller's action somewhere before `return`.

Comment: Thanks Bizley. It's working. Can I add it in the `helper class` before the `echo` statement instead, as I will be calling that function at different places.

Comment: First of all you should `return` data and not `echo` it. It can be anywhere as long as it affects current response.

Comment: ok Bizley. I will change it to return instead of echo (but changing it to return is giving me empty result. I'm checking the code on postman and there is nothing in the output). And I added the statement in `behaviors()` method in controller

Comment: By adding `\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;` you don't need to use any Helper classes, not even `$userArray = ArrayHelper::toArray($user);`, just try to return `$user`

Comment: @ASN see my answer below

Answer (score 56):

Since Yii 2.0.11 there is a dedicated [`asJson()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller#asJson()-detail) method to return a response in JSON format. Run:

```
return $this->asJson($array);
```

in your controller action.

Comment: If returning a big chunk of HTML it works really slow, can't get why

Comment: Try to disable debugging completely and see whether that improves the loading time. I have several Yii2 projects that had loading time issues and by step by step disabling modules/components I found that it was the Yii2-debug component which slowed the whole application server side down.

Answer (score 7):

Simply Add this in controller

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{

    \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: thx, best solution for apps with a few api controllers in addition to base app

Answer (score 1):

```
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\web\Response;
```

Firstly include the 2 lines above at the top of your controller, then in any of your Controller actions, just before the return statements, include the below

```
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
return Json::encode([
            'message' => 'success'
]);
```

You can build the return array as you deem fit.

Comment: This returned `"{\"message\":\"success\"}"` as string not object!

Comment: you can use this:
`json_encode($your_array,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`

Comment: Json::encode - is redundant, FORMAT_JSON did same

Answer (score 1):

```
use JsonException;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter;


/**
 * @param int $id
 * @return string[]
 * @throws InvalidConfigException
 * @throws JsonException
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function actionViewJson(): array
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    Yii::$app->response->formatters = [
        Response::FORMAT_JSON => [
            'class' => JsonResponseFormatter::class,
            'prettyPrint' => true
        ]
    ];
    
    return ['key' => 'val'];
}
```